# Encipher the following plaintext message using the Vignere method using the key K = [4,2,3]

Tags: vigenere

Encipher the following plaintext message, `Exotic`, using the Vignere method using the
key `K = [4,2,3]`

Can anyone help me get the answer and  why, can't find anything that matches this question online.

Comment: You can't find anything that matches this question online? Seriously? There is tons of material out there on Vigenere. You should start with the description of Vigenere on Wikipedia. Vigenere is a very simple cipher. If there are parts you don't understand, you should clearly describe what you don't understand about them to us. Then we can help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not give a clear description of the problem you are facing. Please edit to include those details.